# argparse module - How to change help format in runtime?

Tags: python, runtime, argparse

Lets say, I've got a parser:

```
self.__parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                            prog = '<...>',
                            fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
```

After it is initialized I want in runtime to change the prog variable in argparser to something else, lets say: 'aaa'.

Code:

```
self.__parser.prog = 'aaa'
```

does NOT work, because argparser caches this prog somwhere inside ts formatters.
Does somebody knows if is it possible to change this property in simple way?

Answer (score 3):

It is my suspicion that the problem is somewhere else in your code, as the code below is allowed to change the prog attribute, demonstrated by the calls to print_help:

```
import argparse
import sys

class MyParser():
    def __init__(self, nm=sys.argv[0]):
        self.__parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=nm, fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
    def change_prog_name(self, nm):
        self.__parser.prog = nm
    def print_help(self):
        self.__parser.print_help()

my_parser = MyParser()
my_parser.print_help()
print 'after prog change:'
my_parser.change_prog_name('aaa')
my_parser.print_help()
```

Output:

> usage: argparse_test.py [-h]
>
> optional arguments:
>    -h, --help  show this help message and exit
>
> after prog change:
> usage: aaa [-h]
>
> optional arguments:
>    -h, --help  show this help message and exit